# Where should I put my Node.js web project folder in Ubuntu 14?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I have created a Node.js web project and I would like to deploy this to my Ubuntu 14 server in order to access it from the internet. What would be the right location in Ubuntu?

Comment: Interesting, related reading: [How To Set Up a Node.js Application for Production on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Location does not matter for node server. You can run it from  any where.  **I am running it from my user home directory.**

There are some steps you need to learn.

(1) You may want to use nginx/apache , and direct nginx/apache to your node port.

(2) You may want to  use npm module called forever , to run is permanently.

Comment: I know it doesn't matter but is there no common place where people put their files?

Comment: @Engo A common place to put files ... in Linux? For some, that is a problem! For others, that is the advantage! It just depends on which camp you're from.